# MacOS blocking onion DNS requests

Tags: macos, dns, tor

I created a VPN server on a linux machine that routes all its traffic thru the Tor network. The scheme is this:

`VPN client -> VPN server -> Tor -> Internet`

Connection works fine and client receives the public Tor IP.

I configured Tor on the server as a Transparent Proxy, and my `torrc` config is this:

```
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
DNSPort 10.8.0.1:53530
TransPort 10.8.0.1:9040
```

I made sure to route DNS requests to Tor as well, and my server `iptables` are:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p udp --dport 53 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:53530
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:9040
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p udp -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.1:9040
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i enp2s0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o enp2s0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i enp2s0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

When I make a request to a website, DNS is not leaking, and using Wireshark I can see that the request is being made to 10.8.0.1:

[image: DNS request]

So I'm pretty sure everything is working, except when I try to make a DNS request to a `.onion` service. On Linux and Android it works as expected, however on MacOS and iOS it doesn't.

I opened Wireshark and made a request to a `.com` host and to a `.onion` host. The `.com` request shows on Wireshark and works fine, however the `.onion` doesn't even show there, so there is something blocking this DNS request before reaching the network interface.

Does anybody have a clue what's blocking the request?

I'm thinking on adding a `.exit` or something to the end of the `.onion` domain, then intercept this request on the server and remove the `.exit` from the request, would it work? The request with an ending other than `.onion` works, just `.onion` request are blocked.

[image: .exit request]

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Inspecting the packages with Wireshark on the server, when I'm using Android (which works fine), when I visit a `.onion` host, this is the result:

```
10.8.0.4 → 10.8.0.1     DNS 68 Standard query 0x6887 A protonirockerxow.onion
10.8.0.1 → 10.8.0.4     DNS 84 Standard query response 0x6887 A protonirockerxow.onion A 10.225.55.81
```

This confirms that the problem is with Apple, since both iOS and MacOS block the `.onion` DNS request, because the server doesn't even receive the first DNS package, it's blocked before reaching the network interface.

Comment: .onion does not use DNS.

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/712

Comment: You are right, but the client is not running tor, so for the client it's a regular hostname. The server receives the DNS query and then passes to tor to handle it, but it emulates a dns query to the client